# Displaying ASCII Art In WPF TextBlock Has Strange Line Breaks

Tags: c#, wpf, ascii

I made a simple app in C# WPF that displays ascii art from an image, the code seems to work but the problem is that whenever I set the text of the textblock to the ascii art it seems to have strange line breaks that have nothing to do with my code

**ASCII In Textblock**

[image: the ASCII Text in TextBlock]

**ASCII In Output Log**

[image: the ASCII Text in Output Window]

Here you can see that the output log displays the art correctly while the textblock has line breaks, also I experimented with TextBox and RichTextBox and they gave me the same result

**Image To Ascii Art Code**

```
void TurnImageToAscii(Bitmap image)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j = 0; j < image.Height; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < image.Width; i++)
            {

                Color pixelColor = image.GetPixel(i,j);
                int brightness = (pixelColor.R + pixelColor.G + pixelColor.B) / 3;
                int charIndex = brightness.Remap(0, 255, 0, chars.Length - 1);
                string c = chars[charIndex].ToString();
                sb.Append(c);

            }
            sb.Append("\n");
        }

        asciiTextBlock.Text = sb.ToString();

    }
```

How can I fix this problem?

**Edit:**
**Remap Function**

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{

    public static int Remap(this int value, int from1, int to1, int from2, int to2)
    {
        return (value - from1) / (to1 - from1) * (to2 - from2) + from2;
    }

}
```

**The chars string:**

```
string chars = "    .:-^$@";
```

this is where the chars array is declared, and it has only been refrenced once in the `TurnImageToAscii` function that I posted in the question above

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="AsciiImageWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AsciiImageWPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid Loaded="Grid_Loaded">
    <ComboBox x:Name="videoDevicesList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="419"/>
    <Button x:Name="start_btn" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="448,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="22" Width="77" Click="btn_start_Click"/>
    <Image x:Name="videoImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="362" Margin="10,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="388" Stretch="Fill"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="asciiTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="410,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="366" Width="380" FontSize="3"/>

</Grid>
```

**Image Used**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem 1: ASCII art not being displayed properly in WPF `TextBlock`:

- ASCII-Art needs to be rendered with a fixed-width (aka monospaced) font.
- Your posted XAML shows you're not setting `FontFamily` on the `TextBlock`. using `<TextBlock>`'s default `FontFamily` which will be Segoe UI.

  - *Segoe UI* is not a monospaced font.
- The problem isn't extra line-breaks being added, but that the rendered lines are being *visually compressed*.
- Change the your XAML to this and it will work as-expected:

  - I've also increased the font-size from `3` to `10`.

```xml
<TextBlock
    x:Name= "asciiTextBlock "
    HorizontalAlignment= "Left "
    Margin= "410,58,0,0 "
    VerticalAlignment= "Top "
    Height= "366 "
    Width= "380 "
    FontSize= "10 "
    FontFamily= "Courier New "
/>
```

#### Screenshot proof:

With the default font:

[image]

With `Courier New`:

[image]

I also made a version that uses Unicode block chars, just to make sure I was decoding the image correctly:

```cs
static readonly Char[] _chars = new[] { ' ', '░', '▒', '▓', '█' };
```

[image]

---

## Problem 2: Performance

#### Use `Bitmap.Lockbits`:

- You can significantly increase performance by using `Bitmap.Lockbits` instead of iterating over `.GetPixel()`.

  - `GetPixel()` is *really slow*: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/406045/Why-the-use-of-GetPixel-and-SetPixel-is-so-ineffic

Something like this:

```cs
unsafe static String RenderPixelsAsAscii_LockBits( FileInfo imageFile )
{
    using( Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile( imageFile.FullName ) )
    {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle( x: 0, y: 0, width: bitmap.Width, height: bitmap.Height );
        BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits( rect: r, flags: ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat );
        try
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( capacity: bitmapData.Width * bitmapData.Height );
            
            Int32 bytesPerPixel = System.Drawing.Image.GetPixelFormatSize( bitmapData.PixelFormat ) / 8;
            Byte* scan0 = (Byte*)bitmapData.Scan0;
            for( Int32 y = 0; y < bitmapData.Height; y++ )
            {
                Byte* linePtr = scan0 + ( y * bitmapData.Stride );
                for( Int32 x = 0; x < bitmapData.Width; x++ )
                {
                    Byte*   pixelPtr = linePtr + ( x * bytesPerPixel );
                    UInt32  pixel    = *pixelPtr;
                    sb.AppendPixel( pixel, bitmapData.PixelFormat );
                }
                sb.Append( '\n' );
            }
            
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            bitmap.UnlockBits( bitmapData );
        }
    }
}

public static void AppendPixel( this StringBuilder sb, UInt32 pixel, PixelFormat fmt )
{
    Byte a;
    Byte r;
    Byte g;
    Byte b;
    
    switch( fmt )
    {
    case PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb:
        {
            r = (Byte)( ( pixel & 0xFF_00_00_00 ) >> 32 );
            g = (Byte)( ( pixel & 0x00_FF_00_00 ) >> 24 );
            b = (Byte)( ( pixel & 0x00_00_FF_00 ) >> 16 );
        }
        break;
        
    case PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb:
        {
            a = (Byte)( ( pixel & 0xFF_00_00_00 ) >> 24 );
            r = (Byte)( ( pixel & 0x00_FF_00_00 ) >> 16 );
            g = (Byte)( ( pixel & 0x00_00_FF_00 ) >>  8 );
            b = (Byte)( ( pixel & 0x00_00_00_FF ) >>  0 );
        }
        break;
    case PixelFormat.etc...:
        // TODO if needed.
    default:
        throw new NotSupportedException( "meh" );
    }
    
    Single avgBrightness = ( (Single)r + (Single)g + (Single)b ) / 3f;
    if     ( avgBrightness <  51 ) sb.Append( '█' );
    else if( avgBrightness < 102 ) sb.Append( '▓' );
    else if( avgBrightness < 153 ) sb.Append( '▒' );
    else if( avgBrightness < 204 ) sb.Append( '░' );
    else                           sb.Append( ' ' );
}
```

- Your code can also be modified to be more efficient with `StringBuilder`:

  - Append `char` values directly instead of converting a `Char` to a `String` with `.ToString()`: *that's just silly*.

    - Using `StringBuilder.Append(Char)` is very fast because it just copies the scalar `char` value directly into `StringBuilder`'s internal char buffer.
    - `String` objects exist on the heap which requires allocation and copying, so they're relatively expensive compared to using `char` values, which don't need to use the heap at all until/unless boxed.
  - Additionally, preallocating the `StringBuilder` by setting `capacity: width * height` means that the `StringBuilder` won't need to reallocate and copy its internal buffer every time it overflows.

    - The default capacity of a `StringBuilder` is only 16 chars, so if you can precompute an upperbound for the final length of a StringBuilder for its constructor's `capacity:` you should do that.

Here's the runtime performance figures I get:

- .NET 6 numbers from running in Linqpad 7 (.NET 6) x64 on a PC with a i7-10700K CPU running Windows 10 20H2 x64.
- .NET 4.8 numbers from running in Linqpad 5's AnyCPU build.
- I benchmarked both a `DEBUG` and a `RELEASE` build for some reason.
- I used `Stopwatch` to measure the time taken to convert the already-loaded `Bitmap` to a `String` - so it doesn't include the time to load the image from disk, nor the time for WPF to render the text, as that's unrelated to my suggested improvements).
- The numbers shown are the best of 3 runs after an initial warmup run.

|  | .NET 6 (RELEASE, x64) | .NET 4.8 (RELEASE, x64) | .NET 6 (DEBUG, x64) | .NET 4.8 (DEBUG, x64) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Your original converter function | 1.41ms | 1.87ms | 2.52ms | 2.90ms |
| Your original converter function, but with improved StringBuilder usage | 1.37ms | 1.76ms | 2.41ms | 2.85ms |
| Using `BitmapSource.CopyPixels` | 0.31ms | 0.26ms |  |  |
| Using `LockBits` instead | 0.04ms | 0.04ms | 0.43ms | 0.13ms |
| Relative performance improvement of `LockBits` compared to `GetPixel` | ~35x | ~46x | ~6x | ~22x |

- The `0.04ms` figure is not a typo. It really is that fast.
- The improved `StringBuilder` usage does help, but I'll agree that the sub-millisecond times shaved off really isn't significant.
- I appreciate that *for this project* on modern hardware, even the worst-case of 2.90ms *isn't bad* for the `GetPixel` approach but I was really surprised at how fast the "slow" approach is now....

  - ...compared to about 17 years ago when I was first learning .NET and wanting to use `System.Drawing` to create a dynamic image-macro<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qe7t.png)</sup> generator for my website and attempting to read even a 500x500px `Bitmap` on my then single-core Pentium 4 1.9Ghz (not even Hyper-Threading) took at least a few seconds, which led me to seek-out a faster way, after all, even my old Pentium 166 could process 640x480-sized bitmap images from ancient video file formats in real-time, so I assumed I was doing something wrong.

---

Here's my code, you should be able to copy+paste this into Linqpad or a new blank C# project:

```cs
const String XAML_TEXT = @"
<Window
    xmlns        =""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""
    xmlns:x      =""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml""
    xmlns:mc     =""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006""
    xmlns:local  =""clr-namespace:AsciiImageWPF""
    Title=""MainWindow""
    
    Width  = ""1024""
    Height = ""1024""
>

<Grid ShowGridLines=""True"">    
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>    
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>      
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>    
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>    
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>     
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        
        <TextBlock
            Grid.Row=""0""
            Grid.Column=""0""
            Text=""Variable-width font, your chars""
        />
        
        <TextBlock
            Grid.Row=""0""
            Grid.Column=""1""
            Text=""Variable-width font, block chars""
        />
        
        <TextBlock
            Grid.Row=""1""
            Grid.Column=""0""
            Text=""Monospace font, your chars""
        />
        
        <TextBlock
            Grid.Row=""1""
            Grid.Column=""1""
            Text=""Monospace font, block chars""
        />
        
        <!-- ############################# -->
        
        <TextBlock
            x:Name=""asciiTextBlockVariableSlow""
            Grid.Row=""0""
            Grid.Column=""0""
            Margin=""0,20,0,0""
            
            FontSize=""8""
            Background=""#f2fff2""
        />
        
        <TextBlock
            x:Name=""asciiTextBlockVariableFast""
            Grid.Row=""0""
            Grid.Column=""1""
            Margin=""0,20,0,0""
            
            FontSize=""8""
            Background=""#ffeeed""
        />
        
        <TextBlock
            x:Name=""asciiTextBlockMonospaceSlow""
            Grid.Row=""1""
            Grid.Column=""0""
            Margin=""0,20,0,0""
            
            FontSize=""8""
            Background=""#f2f7ff""
            FontFamily=""Consolas""
        />
        
        <TextBlock
            x:Name=""asciiTextBlockMonospaceFast""
            Grid.Row=""1""
            Grid.Column=""1""
            Margin=""0,20,0,0""
            
            FontSize=""8""
            Background=""#fffff2""
            FontFamily=""Consolas""
        />

</Grid>
    
</Window>
";

const String IMAGE_PATH = @"C:\Users\YOU\Downloads\2022-03\xfqJC.png";

async Task Main()
{
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader( XAML_TEXT );
    XmlReader    xmlReader    = XmlReader.Create( stringReader );
    Window       window       = (Window)XamlReader.Load( xmlReader );
    window.Show();
        
    ///////
    
    FileInfo imageFile = new FileInfo( IMAGE_PATH );
    
    String orig = RenderPixelsAsAscii_Orig( imageFile );
    
    String orig2 = RenderPixelsAsAscii_Orig_better_StringBuilder( imageFile );

    String bmpSrc = RenderPixelsAsAscii_BitmapSource( imageFile );
    
    String mine = RenderPixelsAsAscii_LockBits( imageFile );
    
    //
    
    TextBlock asciiTextBlockVariableSlow  = (TextBlock)window.FindName( name: "asciiTextBlockVariableSlow" );
    TextBlock asciiTextBlockVariableFast  = (TextBlock)window.FindName( name: "asciiTextBlockVariableFast" );
    TextBlock asciiTextBlockMonospaceSlow = (TextBlock)window.FindName( name: "asciiTextBlockMonospaceSlow" );
    TextBlock asciiTextBlockMonospaceFast = (TextBlock)window.FindName( name: "asciiTextBlockMonospaceFast" );
    
    window.Dispatcher.Invoke( () => {
        
        asciiTextBlockVariableSlow.Text = orig;
        asciiTextBlockVariableFast.Text = mine;
        
        asciiTextBlockMonospaceSlow.Text = orig;
        asciiTextBlockMonospaceFast.Text = mine;
        
    } );
}

static string chars = "    .:-^$@";

static String RenderPixelsAsAscii_Orig( FileInfo imageFile )
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    
    using( Bitmap image = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile( imageFile.FullName ) )
    {
//      sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.Dump( "RenderPixelsAsAscii_Orig: Time to load image from disk." );
        
        sw.Restart();
        
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
        for (int j = 0; j < image.Height; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < image.Width; i++)
            {
                Color pixelColor = image.GetPixel(i,j);
                int brightness = (pixelColor.R + pixelColor.G + pixelColor.B) / 3;
                int charIndex = brightness.Remap(0, 255, 0, chars.Length - 1);
                string c = chars[charIndex].ToString();
                sb.Append(c);

            }
            sb.Append("\n");
        }
        
        sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.Dump( "RenderPixelsAsAscii_Orig: Time to render bitmap as ASCII." );

        //asciiTextBlock.Text = sb.ToString();
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

static String RenderPixelsAsAscii_Orig_better_StringBuilder( FileInfo imageFile )
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    
    using( Bitmap image = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile( imageFile.FullName ) )
    {
//      sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.Dump( "RenderPixelsAsAscii_Orig_better_StringBuilder: Time to load image from disk." );
        
        sw.Restart();
        
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( capacity: image.Width * image.Height );
        
        for (int j = 0; j < image.Height; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < image.Width; i++)
            {
                Color pixelColor = image.GetPixel(i,j);
                int brightness = (pixelColor.R + pixelColor.G + pixelColor.B) / 3;
                int charIndex = brightness.Remap(0, 255, 0, chars.Length - 1);
                sb.Append(chars[charIndex]);

            }
            sb.Append('\n');
        }
        
        sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.Dump( "RenderPixelsAsAscii_Orig_better_StringBuilder: Time to render bitmap as ASCII." );

        //asciiTextBlock.Text = sb.ToString();
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

unsafe static String RenderPixelsAsAscii_LockBits( FileInfo imageFile )
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    
    using( Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile( imageFile.FullName ) )
    {
//      sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.Dump( "RenderPixelsAsAscii_LockBits: Time to load image from disk." );
        
        sw.Restart();
        
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle( x: 0, y: 0, width: bitmap.Width, height: bitmap.Height );
        BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits( rect: r, flags: ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat );
        try
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( capacity: bitmapData.Width * bitmapData.Height );
            
            RenderPixelsAsAsciiInner( bitmapData, sb );
            
            sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.Dump( "RenderPixelsAsAscii_LockBits: Time to render bitmap as ASCII." );
            
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            bitmap.UnlockBits( bitmapData );
        }
    }
}

unsafe static void RenderPixelsAsAsciiInner( BitmapData bitmapData, StringBuilder sb )
{
    // bpp == Length of each pixel in bytes. e.g. 24-bit RGB is 3, and 32-bit ARGB is 4.
    Int32 bitsPerPixel  = System.Drawing.Image.GetPixelFormatSize( bitmapData.PixelFormat );
    if( ( bitsPerPixel % 8 ) != 0 ) throw new NotSupportedException( "Image uses a non-integral-pixel-byte-width format: " + bitmapData.PixelFormat );
    
    Int32 bytesPerPixel = bitsPerPixel / 8;
    
    Byte* scan0 = (Byte*)bitmapData.Scan0;
    
    for( Int32 y = 0; y < bitmapData.Height; y++ )
    {
        Byte* linePtr = scan0 + ( y * bitmapData.Stride );

        for( Int32 x = 0; x < bitmapData.Width; x++ )
        {
            Byte*   pixelPtr = linePtr + ( x * bytesPerPixel );
            UInt32  pixel    = *pixelPtr;
            
            sb.AppendPixel( pixel, bitmapData.PixelFormat );
        }
        
        sb.Append( '\n' );
    }
}


static String RenderPixelsAsAscii_BitmapSource( FileInfo imageFile )
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    
    BitmapImage bmpSrc = new BitmapImage( new Uri( imageFile.FullName ) ); // `class BitmapImage : BitmapSource` btw.
    if( ( bmpSrc.Format.BitsPerPixel % 8 ) != 0 ) throw new NotSupportedException( "Image uses a non-integral-pixel-byte-width format: " + bmpSrc.Format.ToString() );
    
    sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.Dump( "RenderPixelsAsAscii_BitmapSource: Time to load image from disk." );
    sw.Restart();
    
    Int32 w = bmpSrc.PixelWidth; // <-- WARNING: It's a common gotcha to use `BitmapImage.Width` instead of `BitmapImage.PixelWidth`.  *DO NOT USE* `BitmapImage.Width` as that's `double`, not `int`, in "Device Dependent Units" *not* pixels!
    Int32 h = bmpSrc.PixelHeight;
    
    Int32 bytesPerPixel     = bmpSrc.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8;
    Int32 stride            = w * bytesPerPixel; // Why on earth doesn't BitmapSource do this calculation for us like System.Drawing does?
    Int32 bufferLengthBytes = h * stride;
    
    PixelFormat pf = bmpSrc.Format.ToGdiPixelFormat();
    
    Byte[] buffer = new Byte[ bufferLengthBytes ];
    
    bmpSrc.CopyPixels( pixels: buffer, stride: stride, offset: 0 );
    
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( capacity: w * h );
    
    for( Int32 y = 0; y < h; y++ )
    {
        for( Int32 x = 0; x < w; x++ )
        {
            Int32 pixelIdx = ( y * stride ) + ( x * bytesPerPixel );
            
            UInt32 pixel = BitConverter.ToUInt32( buffer, startIndex: pixelIdx );
            
            sb.AppendPixel( pixel, pf );
        }
        
        sb.Append( '\n' );
    }
    
    sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.Dump( "RenderPixelsAsAscii_BitmapSource: Time to render bitmap as ASCII." );
    
    return sb.ToString();
}

static class MyExtensions
{
    public static PixelFormat ToGdiPixelFormat( this System.Windows.Media.PixelFormat wpfPixelFormat )
    {
        if( wpfPixelFormat.Equals( System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Bgra32 ) )
        {
            return PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException( "TODO" );
        }
    }
    
    static readonly Char[] _chars = new[] { ' ', '░', '▒', '▓', '█' }; // "    .:-^$@";
    
    public static void AppendPixel( this StringBuilder sb, UInt32 pixel, PixelFormat fmt )
    {
        Byte a;
        Byte r;
        Byte g;
        Byte b;
        
        switch( fmt )
        {
        case PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb:
            {
                r = (Byte)( ( pixel & 0xFF_00_00_00 ) >> 24 );
                g = (Byte)( ( pixel & 0x00_FF_00_00 ) >> 16 );
                b = (Byte)( ( pixel & 0x00_00_FF_00 ) >>  8 );
            }
            break;
            
        case PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb:
            {
                a = (Byte)( ( pixel & 0xFF_00_00_00 ) >> 24 );
                r = (Byte)( ( pixel & 0x00_FF_00_00 ) >> 16 );
                g = (Byte)( ( pixel & 0x00_00_FF_00 ) >>  8 );
                b = (Byte)( ( pixel & 0x00_00_00_FF ) >>  0 );
            }
            break;
        
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException( "meh" );
        }
        
        AppendPixel( sb, r: r, g: g, b: b );
    }
    
    public static void AppendPixel( this StringBuilder sb, Byte r, Byte g, Byte b )
    {
        Single avgBrightness = ( (Single)r + (Single)g + (Single)b ) / 3f;
        if     ( avgBrightness <  51 ) sb.Append( '█' );
        else if( avgBrightness < 102 ) sb.Append( '▓' );
        else if( avgBrightness < 153 ) sb.Append( '▒' );
        else if( avgBrightness < 204 ) sb.Append( '░' );
        else                           sb.Append( ' ' );
    }
    
    public static int Remap( this int value, int from1, int to1, int from2, int to2)
    {
        return (value - from1) / (to1 - from1) * (to2 - from2) + from2;
    }
}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qe7t.png) Now they're just called *memes*. This was before Facebook, before the time when the Internet went mainstream, now it's just *lame* yaknow?

Screenshot proof: